How to pay quarterly estimated taxes when IRS doesn't let me pay online?
I moved to the US in 2023. I'm a citizen. I started earning income in 2023. I work as a software engineer as an independent contractor. This means I need to pay quarterly estimated taxes. I don't think I had to pay estimated taxes last year because I didn't have a prior tax return. So, I just paid the entire amount during the annual filing today.
I now need to pay estimated taxes for the first quarter of 2024. I tried signing up for EFTPS twice but they never send me the PIN to complete registration. I can't use Direct Pay because it requires a tax file of 2022 at the latest which I don't have. Paying online always results in the error as shown here:

The IRS doesn't respond to my emails regarding the error. I can't seem to file estimated taxes via FreeTaxUSA, etc. How do I pay estimated taxes? Do I just mail them a check?

Yes, you can just mail them a check with the form 1040-ES payment voucher. See the instructions here.
