How to mail quarterly estimated taxes using multiple money orders?
How would one make a quarterly estimated tax payment using money orders when the amount to be paid that quarter is greater than the limit on a money order? Let's assume other options such as online payments, checks, etc. aren't possible.
For example, if I have to pay $4,121 by April 15, 2024, would I mail a single envelope containing one payment voucher for the same along with five money orders ($1,000, $1,000, $1,000, $1,000, and $121 each), or would I mail 5 envelopes, each with its own payment voucher?

I can't see any reason not to mail them in a single envelope.
But the U.S. government accepts personal checks. I think they accept credit cards these days. Why are you fighting with money orders?

For this reason: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/162223/128858
I can't use a check because there's no brick and mortar building that offers them in my area, and ordering checks online at this point will cause me to pay this quarter late.

Credit card via the website worked for me. But, OK,  point granted.

Thanks. Debit card worked thankfully this time. I can't see the payment reflected on irs.gov but I'm hoping for the best.
